# DELTA TABLES - The specified properties do not match the existing properties

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I'm using a set of user properties on DataBricks Delta Tables for metadata management. The problem is when I need to change one of those properties I'm getting the **'FAILED Error: The specified properties do not match the existing properties at /mnt/silver/...'** error message.

Databricks documentation only states that an Exception will be raised and I didn't find any argument to force it to accept the new values.

Is it possible to just update table Properties?

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Sample Code:

```
query = f'''
CREATE  TABLE if not exists  {tableMetadataDBName}.{tableMetadataTableName}
(
... my columns ...
-- COMMON COLUMNS
,Hash  string
,sourceFilename STRING
,HashWithFileDate  string
,Surrogate_Key  STRING
,SessionId  STRING
,SessionRunDate TIMESTAMP
,Year INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( YEAR(fileDate))
,Month INT  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( MONTH(fileDate))
,fileDate   DATE
)
USING DELTA 
COMMENT '{tableDocumentationURL}'
LOCATION "{savePath}/parquet"
OPTIONS(  "compression"="snappy")
PARTITIONED BY (Year, Month, fileDate )
 TBLPROPERTIES ("DataStage"="{txtDataStage.upper()}"
,"Environment"="{txtEnvironment}"
,"source"="{tableMetadataSource}"
,"CreationDate"             = "{tableMetadataCreationDate}"
,"CreatedBy"                = "{tableMetadataCreatedBy}"
,"Project"                  = "{tableMetadataProject}"
,"AssociatedReports"        = "{tableMetadataAssociatedReports}"
,"UpstreamDependencies"     = "{tableMetadataUpstreamDependencies}"
,"DownstreamDependencies"   = "{tableMetadataDownstreamDependencies}"
,"Source"                   = "{tableMetadataSource}"
,"PopulationFrequency"      = "{tableMetadataPopulationFrequency}"
,"BusinessSubject"          = "{tableMetadataBusinessSubject}"
,"JiraProject"              = "{tableMetadataJiraProject}"
,"DevOpsProject"            = "{tableMetadataDevOpsProject}"
,"DevOpsRepository"         = "{tableMetadataDevOpsRepository}"
,"URL"                      = "{tableMetadataURL}") '''

spark.sql(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to change just properties - you need to use "[ALTER TABLE [table_name] SET TBLPROPERTIES ...](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html#set-table-properties)" for that:

```py
query = f"""ALTER TABLE {table_name} SET TBLPROPERTIES ( 
'CreatedBy' = '{tableMetadataCreatedBy}
,'Project'  = '{tableMetadataProject}'
....
)"""
spark.sql(query)
```

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't notice that option on Alter Table.
Regards